# Why is the output on the MOSI line shifted 1 bit over from what I commanded?

Tags: spi

I've been trying to work with an [AD5685R DAC](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD5686R_5685R_5684R.pdf). Per that datasheet, to get `DAC1` to output max voltage (5V), I would perform:

```
SPI.begin();
SPI.setBitOrder(MSBFIRST);
SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE3); // DAC uses CPHA=1, CPOL=1

digitalWrite(CS, LOW);
SPI.transfer(0x31); // upper nibble sends a "write and update" command, lower nibble says "DAC1"
SPI.transfer(0xFF);
SPI.transfer(0xFC); // 14-bit DAC, last 2 bits are dontcares, make them 0
digitalWrite(CS, HIGH);
```

Replace `0xFFFC` with `0x0000` to get 0 volts out.

Sending this command as written somehow writes to `DAC4` instead of `DAC1`! and while 5V will come out when I write `0xFFFC`, I get to 2.5V when writing `0x0000` instead of 0V.

If I command this with a Bus Pirate and directly write the bytes out, it works exactly as desired.

I used the Bus Pirate to sniff the SPI traffic and it turns out I'm not getting what I've commanded. Rather than `0x31 0x00 0x00` for instance, I get `0x18 0x80 0x00`.

If we break this out into bits:

```
0x310000: 0011 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 // commanded
0x188000: 0001 1000 1000 0000 0000 0000 // actually sent
```

So the command actually sent out is shifted by 1 bit!

Here's the bit pattern for 16383 counts (i.e., 2^14-1):

```
0x31FFFC: 0011 0001 1111 1111 1111 1100 // commanded
0x18FFFE: 0001 1000 1111 1111 1111 1110 // actually sent
```

The opcode corresponding to `0x18` is "write to input register 4" (the output occurs because I've pulled the `/LDAC` pin permanently low, see the datasheet), which explains why I'm getting an output on `DAC4` instead of `DAC1`.

This occurs with both a Sparkfun Pro Micro and an Arduino Mega 2560.

What is going on here? Why is the Arduino not sending out what I've actually commanded? Again, writing the hex codes directly to the DAC using a Bus Pirate works perfectly.

Comment: Because something is using the wrong SPI mode.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams this is correct, SPI mode should have been `SPI_MODE2`. [Arduino's SPI page](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPI) doesn't make clear what `CPHA=0` vs `CPHA=1` is (rising vs falling edge active). But maybe I'm just having a hard time comprehending words... Or, the comments on the AD5685R's sample code is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

CPOL is clock **polarity**, and CPHA is clock **phase**.

The SPI modes are:

- Mode 0 (the default) - clock is normally low (CPOL = 0), and the data is sampled on the transition from low to high (leading edge) (CPHA = 0)

[image: SPI Mode 0]

- Mode 1 - clock is normally low (CPOL = 0), and the data is sampled on the transition from high to low (trailing edge) (CPHA = 1)

[image: SPI Mode 1]

- Mode 2 - clock is normally high (CPOL = 1), and the data is sampled on the transition from high to low (leading edge) (CPHA = 0)

[image: SPI Mode 2]

- Mode 3 - clock is normally high (CPOL = 1), and the data is sampled on the transition from low to high (trailing edge) (CPHA = 1)

[image: SPI Mode 3]

---

According to your datasheet:

> Data from the SDIN line is clocked into the 24-bit input shift register on the falling edge of SCLK.

Judging by the diagrams on the datasheet, Mode 1 is what you want. You want the trailing edge of high to low.

More information at [SPI - Serial Peripheral Interface - for Arduino](http://www.gammon.com.au/spi)